# Getting Bootstrap 3 popover to work with jQuery validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to validate a form and use Bootstrap 3 popovers to notify the user of invalid form data. I have the following javascript code for handling the validation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#signup').validate({
        rules: {
            signup_email: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 45
            },
            signup_password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
            },
            'signup[confirm_password]': {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#signup_password"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            signup_email: {
                required: "Please enter your email address",
                maxlength: "Your email address is too long!"
            },
            signup_password: {
                required: "Please enter a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 8 characters long."
            },
            'signup[confirm_password]': {
                required: "Please retype your password",
                equalTo: "Passwords do not match!"
            }
        },
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorClass: 'error',
        validClass: 'success',
        highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
            $(element).popover('show');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) {
            $(element).popover('hide');
        },
        errorPlacement: function(err, element) {
            err.hide();
        }});
    $('#signup_email').popover({
        placement: 'below',
        offset: 20,
        trigger: 'manual'
    });
    $('#signup_password').popover({
        placement: 'below',
        offset: 20,
        trigger: 'manual'
    });
    $('#signup_confirm_password').popover({
        placement: 'below',
        offset: 20,
        trigger: 'manual'
    });
});
```

and the following html form:

```
<input type="email" id="signup_email" name="signup[email]" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" rel="popover" />         
<input type="password" id="signup_password" name="signup[password]" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" rel="popover" />         
<input type="password" id="signup_confirm_password" name="signup[confirm_password]" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Retype Password" rel="popover" />   
<button type="submit" id="signup_send" name="signup[send]" class="btn btn-default">Let&#039;s go.</button>
```

When I submit the form, the validation works fine, but no popovers are being displayed. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
'signup[confirm_password]': {
            required: true,
            equalTo: "#signup_password"
        }

'signup[confirm_password]': {
            required: "Please retype your password",
            equalTo: "Passwords do not match!"
        }
```

signup[confirm_password] should be signup_confirm_password.